# How to generate javadoc from many plugin jar files containing source

Tags: java, jar, javadoc

I have a set of over 500 jar files for a whole range of plugins that we have from a third party, and for each of these jar files there is a source jar file as well. But they have not provided the javadoc.

I want to be able to build the javadocs from the provided source jar files, but can't tell if javadoc.exe will do this for me.  I haven't used it manually for years, so not familiar with the command line options.

One of the guys here showed me how to import the source file into Eclipse so I could browse the Source.  but doing that over 500 times is a very time consuming exercise.

Cheers

Comment: If you are targeting Eclipse and your file names are consistent: you could edit the `.classpath` file with something like sed to add the `sourcepath` attributes.

Comment: The javadoc tool can't do mass javadoc operations like this easily. Sorry.

Comment: The problem is with linking in eclipse, is that I have many plugins I am developing against the framework, so have to modify .classpath for each.  If I then generate javadocs and include external plugins, it only includes the ones that are used, not the whole lot in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because all the source file and plugins jars are together in the same directory I have found a relatively simple solution, using eclipse.

1. In Eclipse -> Open a new workspace (so as not to flood your working area)
2. Under Preferences, select Plug-in Development/Target Platform. Create new Target Platform with all of the plugins included and set as current.
3. In the Plug-in browser view, select all plugins, right click, select Import As -> Source Project. At this point all the source files are loaded into the workspace.
4. In the package explorer. Select Project -> Generate javadocs. **Unfortunately** in this dialog, there is no select all option - so if you have 500 plugins, then you have to select them one-by-one.

And if that finishes without crashing, then all is winner.

NOTE: My first attempt using 32-bit eclipse and javadoc failed, I think due to the number of plugins/files, but I then used a 64-bit Eclipse and Javadoc, which took about an hour, but did work.

Comment: In which Preferences? I don't see Plug-in Development/Target Platform under Window/Preferences.